# Why does Lumia Camera 5.0 refuse to work in Lumia 830 with Denim?

Tags: camera, lumia-denim-update, nokia-lumia-830

I've just bought a Lumia 830 and it was unboxed with Denim Firmware update.

[image]
[image]

When I go to the Store to download the [Lumia Camera 5.0](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=2d7e7fd6-2942-4d77-9842-389c3f62b14d) it does this succesfully.

Unfortunately when I try to start the app it says I don't have Denim Firmware Update installed.

[image]

What's happening?

Comment: I assume you've checked for updates?

Comment: Yes. Forgot to mention. I'm currently using Dev Preview so my phone is update as hell. ;)

Comment: Have you tried / could you try a soft reset?

Comment: @Shawn Didn't solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally find out (but can't confirm myself at the moment).

Looks like *Lumia 830* was released with a half baked *Denim Firmware Update*.

To be allowed to install *Lumia Camera 5* on *Lumia 830* it need to be updated at least to O.S. version **8.10.14226.359** currently unavailable even trough *Dev Preview*.

[Source](http://www.windowscentral.com/unlocked-lumia-830-update-hitting-now-lumia-camera-5-support-tow)

**Edit**

Yesterday my phone finally receive an update as you can see below:

[image]

It said that the phone would update this:

- Windows Phone 8.1 (8.10.14234.375)
- Lumia Update for Windows Phone

Even though the version is above the one I report this update made my phone fully support the new Lumia Camera 5.

One more think: I needed to disable *Dev Preview* again to see the update, something that I've already tried with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the Dev Preview off, reboot the phone and try again.

Comment: I just got done taking a 635 through a bunch of updates, and I can confirm the preview is *not* behind.

Comment: Ok I'll edit thx

Comment: Already done. Nothing changed. No updates pending, no startup of Lumia Camera too.

Comment: At no point is dev preview mentioned?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Just edited my answer. boxa72 answer didn't help when I tried days before because the update was not available. But now it was available just because what he said. So I will upvote because it helped too.